# What are the cubic and $n$th terms of the Taylor expansion of a bivariate function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, hessian-matrix

<sub>For the purposes of this question, assume that ordered pairs, vectors, and column matrices are all equivalent.</sub>

$$\newcommand{r}{\mathbf{r}}\newcommand{b}{\mathbf{b}}\newcommand{H}{\boldsymbol{H}}$$

Consider the following table, which summarizes the $n$th terms of the Taylor expansions of the univariate function $g(x)=\sum u_n(x)$ about the point $x=a$ and the bivariate function $F(x,y)=F(\r)=\sum Z_n(\r)$ about the point $(x,y)=(h,k)=\b$:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
n & u_n(x) & Z_n(\r) \\ \hline
0 & g(a) & F(\b) \\
1 & g'(a)\,(x-a) & \nabla F(\b)\,(\r-\b) \\
2 & g''(a)/2\,(x-a)^2 & \H F(\b)\,(\r-\b)^2 \\
3 & g'''(a)/3!\,(x-a)^3 & ? \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
t & g^{(t)}(a)/t!\,(x-a)^t & ? \\
\end{array}$$

where $\H F(\b)$ is the Hessian matrix of $F$ evaluated at $\b$,

$$\H F(\b) =
\begin{pmatrix}
F_{xx}(h,k) & F_{xy}(h,k) \\
F_{yx}(h,k) & F_{yy}(h,k) \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

How is the definition of $Z_n(\r)$ extended for values $n\ge3$? My gut tells me that it involves $n$th partial derivatives of $F$, that it is not pretty, and that there is no compact notation for it. Also, I am pretty sure that the order of my matrix terms is out of whack for multiplication to be defined, so that might also be messing with my understanding.

Comment: It's not $\H F(\b)\,(\r-\b)^2$, because $(\r-\b)^2$ doesn't even make sense: you can't square vectors. It's $\frac{1}{2}(\r-\b)^T\H F(\b)(\r-\b)$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Okay, I was pretty sure the order of the terms was messing up the multiplication. (See my recent edit.)

Comment: And in general, the answer is that the higher-order analogs are tensors. The Hessian is really a bilinear form, a rank 2 tensor. The third-derivative analog is a rank 3 tensor, and so on. Or you can just write everything in terms of scalars with mixed partial derivatives. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925322/properties-and-notation-of-third-order-and-higher-partial-derivatives

Comment: @symplectomorphic My goodness . . . .  That looks brutal.

Comment: It's not brutal. The point is that with many variables, you have many mixed partials. The 1st order approximation to $f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)$ is $f_x(x-x_0)+f_y(y-y_0)$. The 2nd order is $\frac{1}{2}f_{xx}(x-x_0)^2+f_{xy}(x-x_0)(y-y_0)+\frac{1}{2}f_{yy}(y-y_0)^2$. The 3rd order is $\frac{1}{6}f_{xxx}(x-x_0)^3+\frac{1}{2}f_{xxy}(x-x_0)^2(y-y_0)+\frac{1}{2}f_{xyy}(x-x_0)(y-y_0)^2+\frac{1}{6}f_{yyy}(y-y_0)^3$, and so on. (I've suppressed notation that the derivatives must be evaluated at the point $(x_0,y_0)$, because then the notation is hideous.)

Comment: @symplectomorphic If you would like to expand that (along with the tensor business) into an answer I would upvote it and probably even $\color{green}{\checkmark}$ it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $n$-th order terms of the Taylor polynomial of a sufficiently differentiable bivariate function $f(x,y)$ are determined by the $2^n$ mixed partial derivatives of order $n$.

You can think of these $2^n$ derivatives as encoded in a

$$\underbrace{2\times\cdots\times2}_{n\,\text{times}}$$

array. When $n=1$ this is a vector with $2$ components. When $n=2$ this is a $2\times 2$ matrix, the Hessian, with $4$ components. When $n=3$ we have a $2\times2\times2$ "cube" of third partials, with $8$ components. When $n=4$ we have a $2\times2\times2\times2$ four-dimensional hypercube of fourth partials, with $16$ components. And so on. (This is a general result: for a function of $m$ independent variables instead of $2$, just replace $2$ with $m$.) If you insist on taking this perspective (of $n$-dimensional arrays), you must talk about tensors of order $n$. It's a little more down-to-earth, if less succinct, to think about the direct expansion in terms of the mixed partial derivatives, instead of in terms of tensors.

By [Clairaut's theorem](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_theorem_on_equality_of_mixed_partials) on the equality of mixed partials, many of these $2^n$ mixed partials are equivalent. For example, $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$, and $f_{xxy}=f_{xyx}=f_{yxx}$, and $f_{xyy}=f_{yxy}=f_{yyx}$. (I'm glossing over some technicalities about the domain on which these partial derivatives are defined.) So the arrays of mixed partials have a great deal of symmetry to them. In general, there will only be $n+1$ different mixed partials of order $n$. When $n=2$, there's $3$ distinct mixed partials: $f_{xx}$, $f_{xy}$, and $f_{yy}$. When $n=3$, there's $4$ distinct mixed partials: $f_{xxx}$, $f_{xxy}$, $f_{xyy}$, and $f_{yyy}$. This symmetry greatly simplifies the Taylor expansion. The symmetry is similar, but harder to notate, when you have $m$ independent variables instead of $2$.

Now let's work out the bivariate case explicitly.

A specific mixed partial of order $n$, say

$$f_{\underbrace{x\cdots x}_{i}\underbrace{y\cdots y}_{j}}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i\,y^j}:=f_{i,j}$$

where $i+j=n$, contributes a term

$$\frac{1}{n!}f_{i,j}(x-x_0)^i(y-y_0)^j$$

to the Taylor expansion. But ${n\choose i}$ of these terms are the same, by the symmetry mentioned above. (We can choose any of the $i$ places for $x$.)

So the $n$-th order terms of the Taylor expansion (there are $n+1$ one of them) look like

$$\frac{1}{n!}f_{n,0}(x-x_0)^n+\frac{1}{n!}{n\choose 1}f_{n-1,1}(x-x_0)^{n-1}(y-y_0)+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!}{n\choose n-1}f_{1,n-1}(x-x_0)(y-y_0)^{n-1}+\frac{1}{n!}f_{0,n}(y-y_0)^n$$

or, more succinctly,

$$\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{i=0}^n{n\choose i}f_{n-i, i}(x-x_0)^{n-i}(y-y_0)^i$$

Note that when I write $f_{n-i,i}$, I mean the mixed partial *evaluated* at the point $(x_0, y_0)$.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor: I fixed that typo 9 minutes ago.

Comment: If I wanted to write the bivariate function as an infinite series, how would I incorporate the finite sum you’ve provided? I would have to add together that value for $n=0$ onward, correct?

Comment: Yes; the Taylor series is

$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{1}{j!}\sum_{i=0}^j{j\choose i}f_{j-i, i}(x-x_0)^{j-i}(y-y_0)^i$$

where $f_{0,0}$ just means $f(x_0,y_0)$.